# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token instanceof (with Chrome Javascript console)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am surprised that the following code when input into the Chrome js console:

```
{} instanceof Object
```

results in this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token instanceof

Can anyone please tell me why that is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The grammar for *instanceof* is:

```
RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression
```

per [*ECMA-262 §11.8*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8).

The punctuator `{` at the start of a statement is seen as the start of a block, so the following `}` closes the block and ends the statement.

The following `instanceof` operator is the start of the next statement, but it can't be at the start because it must be preceded by a *RelationalExpression*, so the parser gets a surprise.

You need to force `{}` to be seen as an object literal by putting something else at the start of the statement, e.g.

```
({}) instanceof Object
```

Comment: Another workaround: `Boolean({} instanceof Object)` will output `true`

Answer (score 3):

`{}`, in that context, is a *block*, not an object literal.

You need change the context (e.g. by wrapping it in `(` and `)`) to make it an object literal.

```
({}) instanceof Object;
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin: it works. But can you explain why the operator is not recognized? Why this error message?

Comment: @balteo — Because you are putting it after a code block instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this:

```
var a = {}
a instanceof Object
```

outputs `true`, which is the expected output.

However, in your case

```
{} instanceof Object
```

The above doesn't outputs true.

The latter **isn't** the same as the first one. In the first case, we create an object literal, while in the second case we don't. Hence you get this error.

Comment: Umm... But why does it balk at the operator. Why doesn't it even recognize the operator?

Comment: @balteo `{}` This is not an operator in JavaScript. We can place inside `{}` pairs of keys/values in order an object to be created. It is the shortest way of creating an object in JavaScript. It isn't like the invocation operator `()`, which when be appended after a functional expression this expression will be executed or like `+` operator and so on.

Comment: I meant why does it balk at the `instanceof` operator?

Comment: @balteo I think the best explanation on this is of `RobG`.

Comment: @Christos "{} This is not an operator in JavaScript. We can place inside {} pairs of keys/values in order an object to be created." -- this should be included in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var p = {}
p instanceof Object
```